# how do I get source map working for npm linked angular library

Tags: angular, source-maps

I have created angular 7 library with `ng g library @my-org/some-lib` and use it in separate angular app by `npm link` to be able to develop both app and a library.

Now I found that in dev tools I see the library as a separate `my-org-some-lib` bundled js file resolved from the `vendor.js.map` yet it is not resolving further to the `sourceMappingURL=my-org-some-lib.js.map` which exists in the `my-org-some-lib.js` and the map file is actually generated in a builded library.

Comment: Not sure but looks like the same issue. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader/issues/40. Please check LeonardoGentile answer in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some time of dealing with combined library sources finally I found a solution:

1. in the `angular.json` in `projects.app.architect.build.options` path there need to include

```
"options": {
  "sourceMap": true,
  "vendorSourceMap": true,
  "preserveSymlinks": true, // <-- bonus - to use npm link'ed libraries
  // ...
  // note that json format does not allows comments ;)
}
```

2. to avoid sourcemaps in production ensure (should be there by default)

```
"configurations": {
  "production" :{
    "sourceMap": false
    // ...
  }
}
```

3. there was a bug in `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, version >= 0.801.3 should work ok

the above solution is taken from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15531

Comment: These options were removed in angular 8. The options shown by [Azerafati are more up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69142535/542251) though I think this [explains there location better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56669585/542251)

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me was this from here https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration

```
"sourceMap": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": true,
  "hidden": false,
  "vendor": true
}
```