# vendorSourceMap deprecated in Angular CLI 7.2

Tags: angular-cli

Starting with `Angular 7.2`, the `vendorSourceMap` option is deprecated:

```
> ng serve --vendor-source-map

Option "vendorSourceMap" is deprecated.
```

Official documentation of [ng serve](https://angular.io/cli/serve) says `vendorSourceMap` is deprecated, but gives no alternative way of resolving library sources:

> --vendorSourceMap=true|false
>
> **Deprecated**
>
> Resolve vendor packages sourcemaps.
>
> Default: false

What is the correct, non-deprecated way, then to resolve vendor source maps in Angular 7.2?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/32a096f3f084fd58719d9009be4ff1d6666b6565/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/build-options.ts#L29), `--sourceMap` will be used in the future. Looks like they are moving away from the flag being a Boolean to allowing more options. Maybe try something like `--sourceMap=vendor`(?)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The correct `angular.json` options are

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "sourceMap": {
      "scripts": true,
      "styles": true,
      "vendor": true
    },
...
```

Verified on `10.0.*`.
(Updated verfied version from `7.2.15` > `10.0.*`)

Btw, the documentation is really poor on this matter, and I could not find a blog post or resource with an example.

Comment: Not that this explains much, but at least it lists the options... https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-and-source-map-configuration

Comment: Any idea how to set the sourceMap configuration from the command line `--sourceMap=` to have scripts be true and vendor be false?

Comment: @ThomasJahncke never tried. Honestly the quicker way is to debug the serve script and see where those options go.

Comment: @LppEdd thank you for your reply.  FWIW, I am using ng build --watch instead of serve, but that is a different topic.  I wasn't able to get the `angular.json` config to work with that setup so I thought I would try the command line.  How do you debug the serve / build script?

Comment: @ThomasJahncke you need to check if the JSON "build" configuration supports the above settings first. It might not. It's a bit difficult for me to answer because I don't work anymore on Angular (or frontend stuff) since February 2020. I'll check if I still have a project tho

Comment: @ThomasJahncke as far as I remember you'll find the NG scripts under the angular NPM libraries, probably angular-devkit

Answer (score 0):

In version 12 this option is not allowed , so you can debug your library by
modifying angular.json : and make verbose option equals to true

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",

          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "testAdmin:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "testAdmin:build:development",
              "verbose": true <--- **modify this // or add this option**
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

Comment: This does not work for the problem. I tried it in Angular 16.